# How can I launch gnome-terminal with unique titles for multiple tabs?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I've seen [various posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line) about launching gnome-terminal with multiple tabs and the script below is working for me.  That is to say, this script will launch gnome-terminal with various working directories or profiles. . .

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal \
--tab --working-directory=$HOME/notes  \
--tab --working-directory=$HOME/puppet \
--tab --profile=root-beamish           \
--tab --profile=odyssey                \
--tab --profile=root
```

... but I'd like to set a unique title for each tab.

In the case where a tab has its own profile I can change the title from within gnome-terminal with `Edit | Profiles | (NAME) | Edit | Title and Command` and then change "Initial Title" to what I want and "When terminal commands set their own titles" from "Replace initial title" to "Keep initial title".  However, I'd rather not create a unique profile for every tab.  I'd like a generic solution.

I've tried adding `--title='MyTitle'` but it doesn't seem to help.  I'm using GNOME 2.28.2 on CentOS 6.

Comment: An old question, but I've just solved it on Ubuntu and would like to share my solution. I've written [a script](https://github.com/halfer/terminal-tweak) which sets a title based on the cwd. Since `gnome-terminal` now supports per-tab working directories, this script can be wired straight into your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-t` option. (see `gnome-terminal --help-terminal-options`)

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab -t "notes" --working-directory=$HOME/notes  \
--tab -t "puppet" --working-directory=$HOME/puppet \
--tab -t "beamish" --profile=root-beamish           \
--tab -t "odyssey" --profile=odyssey                \
--tab -t "root" --profile=root
```

---

#### -------- updated at 2011-11-15 22:00:00 --------

So... that worked for me on Solaris 11 Express, with gnome-terminal 2.30.2.

Since then, I've been able to test it on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty), which uses 2.32.1, and found exactly the same behavior as you.

In the case of Ubuntu, I was able to track it to the ubuntu `.bashrc` file.  In particular, the section that looks like:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

In this case, the PS1 variable is being expanded for terminal types matching `xterm*` and `rxvt*`.

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

specifically the part between `PS1="\[\e]0;` and `\a\]`.   Those get turned into the window title.

Once I commented out that whole `case` statement, the behavior of gnome-terminal with the `-t` option worked as expected.  I'll see if I can find a CentOS 6 box to test this with, too.

---

#### -------- updated at 2017-11-1 09:38:00 --------

So it looks like more recent versions of Gnome-Terminal have made away with some useful features, like the simple `-t` option to set terminal titles.

It *is* still possible to set terminal titles at runtime, it's just ugly as hell now.  You can use `printf` or `echo` in the command to effect a title.

For example:

To start a terminal window with 1 tab, titled 'My Fancy Title' using `printf`:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "printf \"\e]2;My Fancy Title\a\"; bash -i"'
```

To start a terminal window with 2 tabs, one running top, and one with a title, using `echo`:

```
gnome-terminal \
--tab -e 'bash -c "echo -ne \"\033]0;my tab running top\007\"; top"' \
--tab -e 'bash -c "echo -ne \"\033]0;My Fancy Title\007\"; bash -i"'
```

This does at least offer an option for setting the terminal title at runtime.

See [this post for an option to put a simple function in your `~/.bashrc` to allow for setting and resetting the title at will](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186167/4721).

Comment: Thanks but `-t` is equivalent to `--title` which doesn't work for me, as I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: do you by any chance have a customized, or complex, PS1 to set up your shell prompt?  If so, can you try unsetting your PS1, and re-run your script?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help either.  What Linux distribution are you using, Tim?

Comment: Actually, I was testing on Solaris 11 Express, which uses gnome-terminal 2.30.2.   I've just tried it with ubuntu and found exactly the same behavior you have.   I'll update the answer with what I found.

Comment: "Option "-t" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal"

It says this when I specify this option.

Comment: rumor has it that `-t` may be coming back, but I updated the answer with a solution that works (with gnome-terminal version 3.18.3 on ubuntu 16.04), but is ugly.

Comment: `-t` is working again, running 3.28.1

Comment: worked for me : `gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c 'bash -c "printf \"\e]2;My Fancy Title\a\""; echo hi; echo hi; echo hi; echo hi; sleep 5'`

Answer (score 4):

When I did a

> $ gnome-terminal -t "MyTitle"

The new terminal had "MyTitle" as the title for a moment and immediately was replaced by the default title.

I went to

> Edit | Profiles | (Default) | Edit | Title and Command

And changed "When terminal command set their own titles:" to "Keep initial title", the above command launched a terminal with "MyTitle" as the title.

Comment: The reason this works is because it disables the title being set in a `.bashrc` as mentioned in the update to the [answer above](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24742/102285). The downside is that it stops the title being changed globally for all terminals using the profile.

Answer (score 1):

## GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 (Ubuntu 18.04)

### using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2

To make a tab in a directory with a title (running the default shell):

```
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory "$SOME_DIR"  --title "Some Title"
```

If you want multiple tabs, just run this command multiple times.

To run a **0 argument** command append  `-- cmd`. e.g

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title "CALC" -- python
```

No idea what you do if you want arguments. Note:
`man gnome-terminal` is out of date. `gnome-terminal --help` is of more help.

Answer (score 0):

This creates two tabs, each opened to a directory "foo" or "bar", with tab titles "foo" and "bar"

`gnome-terminal --tab -t foo -e 'sh -c "cd foo; sh"' --tab -t bar -e 'sh -c "cd bar; sh"'`