# How to rename terminal tab title in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Used to be able to right click on the tab and change the title. Not sure how to do this anymore. Just upgraded to Fedora 21.

EDIT: I have switched from gnome-terminal to ROXterm

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Create a function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

Then use your new command to set the terminal title. It works with spaces in the name too

```
set-title my new tab title
```

It is possible to subsequently use `set-title` again (original PS1 is preserved as `ORIG`).

Comment: Please explain the details of how this works and why.

Comment: Also, per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824603/4561887) and many comments all around this answer, you should be using `$@` instead of `$*` here to capture all input parameters to the call to `set-title`.

Comment: I figured it out. See here for a detailed description, as well as cases where I demonstrate how to get dynamically-changing titles that change with the time or present working directory, for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/566383#566383.

Comment: @GabrielStaples No, `"a$@b"` expands to `"aarg1" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4b"` (several words), whereas `"a$*b"` expands to `"aarg1 arg2 arg3 arg4b"` (one word). In this case, `$*` is what we want (actually, the user should supply a single quoted argument, but to accept multiple arguments as a convenience `$*` is the appropriate solution in this specific case (even though in most cases `$@` is the right option).

Comment: Can you add an explanation how to include this in your `usr/local/bin`? I tried defining the function and then calling `set-title "$@"` in a shell script stored there, but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks my man!! After searching a bunch of "echo -e ..." and "printf ..." finally this did the trick.

Answer (score 54):

The `user title` code was removed<sup>1</sup> from `gnome-terminal 3.14`. To set the title, you could use an escape sequence:

```
printf "\e]2;YOUR TITLE GOES HERE\a"
```

or e.g. with `bash`:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;YOUR TITLE GOES HERE\007"
```

Arguments `-ne` to `echo` do not add a newline character and interpret Escape-sequences (such as `\033`).

---

<sup>1: see gnome [bug 724110](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724110) and gnome [bug 740188](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740188).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for a link to the discussions. I guess the answer to this was NO. A funny quote from one of the links: "modern users do not use terminals". LOL.

Comment: This doesn't work for me:  Fedora 21, Bash 3.14.3.

Comment: It works on fc22 also..

Comment: works with centos 7

Comment: Apparently, it's coming back... "Yeah sorry, the --title option is restored in GNOME 3.20 (March 2016 release), which we released half a year ago, but Ubuntu 16.04 shipped with GNOME 3.18 (September 2015 release), which had removed this option."  Michael Catanzaro's 2016-09-01 18:41:45 UTC comment #31 (from second bug, 740188)

Comment: @sage - there is no feature, Michael's comment there is about the `--title` option which I can confirm that was indeed restored. However, the Q here is about the right-click option to rename the currently open tab - a different issue...

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti - I had tested `--title`, but had expected it to behave similarly (for window title) to how the tab title behaved, which persists despite control sequences that change it.  I just disabled all of my control sequences and confirmed that `--title` works and you are right that I confused the two features as being related.  I'll stick with roxterm unless they bring back the tab titles.

Answer (score 27):

New versions of gnome-terminal just thrown away most helpful professional features. :-(

I have tried to setup and get an older version of gnome-terminal running and also compared alternatives.

If `terminator` is too exotic for you, the `mate-terminal` is a great option! It is a fork of gnome-terminal and just keeps all the good features:

- you can open multiple tabs from the command line giving them different titles

  ```
  mate-terminal --tab -t "aaa" --tab -t "bbb" --tab -t "ccc"
  ```
- you can set up a keyboard shortcut (I use Ctrl+Shift-**i**) to set a t**i**tle

Comment: Guake is also not a bad variant

Answer (score 23):

*My new script as of March 2021:*

I have a new version of the "set title" function now. For the latest version of it, search [my `~/.bash_aliases` file somewhere around here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bash_aliases#L250). Here's what it might look like. It has a `-h` help menu now, and instead of relying on a backup of the `PS1` variable the first time you run it, which is finicky, it simply uses the `sed` 's'tream 'ed'itor command and a regular expression to strip the existing title string from the `PS1` variable instead.

```bash
gs_set_title() {
    CMD="gs_set_title"
    # Help menu
    if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "-?" ]; then
        echo "Set the title of your currently-opened terminal tab."
        echo "Usage:   $CMD any title you want"
        echo "   OR:   $CMD \"any title you want\""
        echo "   OR (to make a dynamic title which relies on variables or functions):"
        echo "         $CMD '\$(some_cmd)'"
        echo "     OR  $CMD '\${SOME_VARIABLE}'"
        echo "Examples:"
        echo "         1. static title"
        echo "           $CMD my new title"
        echo "         2. dynamic title"
        echo "           $CMD 'Current Directory is \"\$PWD\"'"
        echo "       OR  $CMD 'Date and time of last cmd is \"\$(date)\"'"
        return $EXIT_SUCCESS
    fi

    TITLE="$@"
    # Set the PS1 title escape sequence; see "Customizing the terminal window title" here:
    # https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title
    ESCAPED_TITLE="\[\e]2;${TITLE}\a\]"

    # Delete any existing title strings, if any, in the current PS1 variable. See my Q here:
    # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310665/how-to-replace-terminal-title-using-sed-in-ps1-prompt-string
    PS1_NO_TITLE="$(echo "$PS1" | sed 's|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||g')"
    PS1="${PS1_NO_TITLE}${ESCAPED_TITLE}"
}
```

---

*Original answer:*

[@Weston Ganger](https://westonganger.com/) wrote this function ([and posted it here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/186167#186167)) to put into `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

You can then set a terminal title by calling `set-title TERMINAL NAME` (quotes around the name are optional).

It looked pretty mysterious to me (see my comments under [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/186167#186167)), so I spent a few hours last night reading and studying to figure out what the heck he had done and why it worked. Here's what I found:

1. As of `gnome-terminal` 3.16.2 or so ([see comments under this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title/22417#22417)), "the option `--title` is no longer supported." Otherwise, you'd just do `gnome-terminal --title="my title"`, [like I used to do here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563).
2. Per [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824603/4561887), and many comments all around this answer, you should be using `$@` instead of `$*` to represent all input arguments in the script above. Apparently `$@` is less bug-prone and more compatible, as it's the POSIX way to represent "all input arguments". Therefore, in my version below I use `$@` instead of `$*`.
3. It turns out that in nearly any terminal (so long as the given terminal supports it), there are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are a form of "[in-band signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-band_signaling)", which can be used to set a terminal title. See the section titled "**Customizing the terminal window title**" in this [most-excellent archlinux wiki here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title). The Bash escape sequence to set the terminal title looks like this: `\[\e]2;new title\a\]`, and to apply this title to your terminal window, all you have to do is modify its ["Prompt String 1", or `PS1` variable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Prompts), by adding this "set title" escape sequence *after* your current Prompt String 1, like this: `PS1="${PS1}\[\e]2;new title\a\]"`. *Since `gnome-terminal` no longer supports the `--title` argument, this appears to be the only way to set the title anymore.*

Now, here is my version of Weston Ganger's function, with extensive explanatory comments. This will be going into [my dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) so I never lose it:

```bash
# Set the title string at the top of your current terminal window or terminal window tab
set-title() {
    # If the length of string stored in variable `PS1_BAK` is zero...
    # - See `man test` to know that `-z` means "the length of STRING is zero"
    if [[ -z "$PS1_BAK" ]]; then
        # Back up your current Bash Prompt String 1 (`PS1`) into a global backup variable `PS1_BAK`
        PS1_BAK=$PS1 
    fi

    # Set the title escape sequence string with this format: `\[\e]2;new title\a\]`
    # - See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title
    TITLE="\[\e]2;$@\a\]"
    # Now append the escaped title string to the end of your original `PS1` string (`PS1_BAK`), and set your
    # new `PS1` string to this new value
    PS1=${PS1_BAK}${TITLE}
}
```

### Usage examples:

- **Static title strings** (title remains fixed):

  - `set-title my tab 1` OR `set-title "my tab 1"`
  - `set-title $PWD` OR `set-title "$PWD"`
- **Dynamic title strings** (title updates each time you enter any terminal command): you may use function calls or
  variables within your title string and have them *dynamically* updated each time you enter a new command.
  Simply enter a command or access a global variable inside your title string. **Be sure to use *single quotes*
  around the title string for this to work!**:

  - `set-title '$PWD'` - this updates the title to the Present Working Directory every time you `cd` to a new
    directory!
  - `set-title '$(date "+%m/%d/%Y - %k:%M:%S")'` - this updates the title to the new date and time every time
    it changes *and* you enter a new terminal command! The format looks like this: `02/06/2020 - 23:32:58`

## Related:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563
2. My dotfiles (config files, scripts, & generic user settings): https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles

## Main References:

1. [my question] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310665/how-to-replace-terminal-title-using-sed-in-ps1-prompt-string
2. [How to rename terminal tab title in gnome-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/186167#186167)
3. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title
4. https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/
5. [Why is bash's prompt variable called PS1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32096/why-is-bashs-prompt-variable-called-ps1/32097#32097)
6. Bash Reference Manual: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: Just explain please what this string does: "\[\e]2;new title\a\]". Great explaination!

Comment: @AmanGupta, `\[\e]2;` is literally just a magic string delimiter sequence that means "this is the start of the terminal title in the terminal PS1 variable", and `\a\]` is literally just the string delimiter sequence that the makers of the Linux shell chose to mean "this is the end of the terminal title when setting the title string by writing it to the terminal PS1 variable". That's all there is to it. It's comparable to packetizing or serializing binary data packets over serial, for instance. You just choose some arbitrary 4-byte number to denote the start of a packet, and another...

Comment: ...arbitrary 4-byte number to denote the end of the binary packet. Then, when searching through binary data you look for those markers to find a whole packet of data. This is the same with this textual string. They just chose some sequences to mark the beginning and end of the title string which is stored in the shell's `PS1` (Prompt String 1) variable.

Comment: Your effort is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: working in gnome-terminal 3.40.2

Comment: Thank you for your research. I learned a lot and improved on this answer into mine which is a one-liner.

Comment: Lol. Ammmazing.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 you may need to:

```
PS1=$
PROMPT_COMMAND=
echo -en "\033]0;New title\a"
```

I list this an more info about it at [link](http://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/Change-the-title-of-a-terminal-on-Ubuntu-1604).

Comment: This destroys the old prompt text. Just use one line `PS1="$PS1\[\e]0;New title\a\]"` instead. Or better yet, setup as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found that no easy way to set tab title from right click of mouse (the way I and most of my colleagues are used to). It was so irritiating at the sametime :(. So in our case, the solution was to switch the terminal. So search for alternatives like sakura, etc and finally settled on xfce-terminal, use the below command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
```

It provides profile and the command to right click and change tab name. All other features are similar to Gnome

Answer (score 1):

put this in .bashrc:

```
function title() { 
  p1='echo -ne "\033]0;' 
  p2='\007"'
  PROMPT_COMMAND=$p1$@$p2 
  p1= 
  p2=
}
```

Comment: And run this with 'title your new title'

Answer (score 1):

When you run a resident program like top or ssh, the tab is properly labeled.

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e top -t "aaa" --tab -e top -t "bbb"
```

Comment: How do you also set `--working-directory` at the same time? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/555378/64783

Answer (score 1):

For me `-t` parameter still works (gnome-terminal v3.36.1.1), but only while a command is executing:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t browser-sync  -- npm run sync
```

so in the example above while browser-sync started by npm script is running - the title is there, and when it stopped.. then the tab is closed lol.
Well if you do just

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t my-title
```

without command - you will still see 'my-title' in tab header but for fraction of second only.

Answer (score 1):

## Customize `.bashrc` so `TERM_TITLE` variable sets your terminal title

### How to setup

#### Common case: `.bashrc` already sets terminal title

For the most cases (such as on Ubuntu), the default `.bashrc` has this line:

```bash
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

which sets terminal title everytime prompt text `PS1` is displayed.
The part between `\[\e]0;` and `\a\]` determines what the title is going to be. We are going to replace that part so the line becomes:

```bash
PS1="\[\e]0;\${TERM_TITLE:-${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w}\a\]$PS1"
```

This basically says:

1. If variable `TERM_TITLE` is set and not null, then use its value as the title
2. Otherwise, use the default title

#### Other cases

If your `.bashrc` doesn't already have such a line that contains
`PS1="\[\e]0;...\a\]$PS1"`, just add it.

Or, even better, switch the ordering around into `PS1="$PS1\[\e]0;...\a\]"` instead.
This way, even if `PS1` somehow already have a sequence that sets terminal title, we will overwrite it.

### How to use

- Set `TERM_TITLE='new title'` whenever you want terminal title to change.
- Use `unset TERM_TITLE` or `TERM_TITLE=` to restore terminal title back to default.

### Pitfalls

Note the escaped `$` sign in `\${TERM_TITLE:-...}`. This means `TERM_TITLE` is evaluated when `PS1` is processed for prompting.

If instead you write `${TERM_TITLE:-...}` without the preceeding `\`,
then `TERM_TITLE` will be evaluated when `PS1` is set and the prompt will not update according to current value of `TERM_TITLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion onto @Weston Ganger's answer, if you want to automatically set a title upon opening a new Gnome terminal, then add this to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ ! -z "$SET_TITLE" ]; then
    set-title $SET_TITLE;
    export SET_TITLE=;
fi
```

Then launch a terminal like:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "export SET_TITLE=\"my title\"; bash -i"'
```

and it will automatically run `set-title` to apply the title.

Answer (score 0):

one line solution, add following line in your .bashrc

```
alias tab_name='read -p "Name to Assign:" tabname ;  printf "\e]2;$tabname\a" '
```

now type tab_name in terminal i.e.

```
user:~$ tab_name  
Name to Assign: ( type desired name here! )
```

**Done**