# Call a .bashrc function from a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, gnome-terminal, function

I want to be able to name a terminal tab so I can keep track of which one is which. I found this function ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186167)) and put it in my `.bashrc`:

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

and now when I call `set-title my new tab name` the tab name is changed as expected to "my new tab name". The problem is that I want to open a new tab and name it using `set-title`. The way I have tried to do this, is like this:

`gnome-terminal --geometry=261x25-0+0 --tab -e "bash -c 'set-title tab1; sleep 10'" --tab -e "bash -c 'set-title tab2; sleep 10"`

However, now I get the following error message:

`bash: set-title: command not found`

And I think this is to do with the new gnome tab not knowing about the `.bashrc` function yet.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: For non-interactive use, why involve the `$PS1` hack? Just `echo` the magic string that sets the title.

Comment: So, just replace `PS1=` with `echo`?

Comment: @Haych: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant of using function `set-title` you can create command with this functionality, so remove function `set-title()` that you add from `~/.bashrc` and create a file `/usr/local/bin/set-title`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007"
```

Add chmod: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/set-title`.
And after you re-open terminal you can use this command by: `set-title TEST` (If you have `/usr/local/bin/` in your `$PATH`).

And then you can use it when creating new tab by this way:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=261x25-0+0 \
    --tab -e "bash -c 'set-title TAB1; sleep 10'" \
    --tab -e "bash -c 'set-title TAB2; sleep 10'"
```

If you somehow don't have `/usr/local/bin/` in your `$PATH`, you can try with absolute path to the set-title command:

```
--tab -e "bash -c '/usr/local/bin/set-title TAB1; sleep 10'"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The function I am using actually puts text in the tab so then i can know which is which. This didn't do that for me unfortunately!

Comment: But my solution works, and puts text in title. When I run above command, I get: http://i.imgur.com/587bmcG.png If you don't have this results you makes something wrong, you have some error?

Answer (score -1):

If you want your .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, etc initialization scripts run, start gnome-terminal with `--login` option.