# How to call .bashrc function in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, function

```bsh
~/.bashrc
----
example()
{
    echo "example function"
}
```

If I use this in a shell script

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

example
```

I get command not found.

I have tried

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

source ~/.bashrc
example
```

but it doesn't work.

---

I found these answers and think this question deserves to live here with a clear question and clear and concise answer.

1. [Call a .bashrc function from a bash shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320734/call-a-bashrc-function-from-a-bash-shell-script)
2. [How do you call a function defined in .bashrc from the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500499/how-do-you-call-a-function-defined-in-bashrc-from-the-shell)

Comment: When you said "but it doesn't work" can you explain?  Does it give an error?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that even if you run your program with `#!/bin/bash`, it will not execute .bashrc, as it is a non interactive instance of `bash`.