# How to rename terminal window from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I am writing a bash script where I pretend to open a new terminal window (in this case a gnome-terminal), execute some commands and change the title of the terminal window.

In order to change the title of the terminal window I am using the function *set-title* as proposed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186167/453913). The approach works perfectly when I open manually a new terminal and type inside the terminal *set-title MY_TITLE*. But in this case, from within a bash script it is not working even if I *source* the *.bashrc* file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "echo Hello from terminal 1; set-title Terminal 1; exec /bin/bash";

gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc; echo Hello from terminal 2; set-title Terminal 2; exec /bin/bash";
```

The two new opened terminals show the same error:

```bsh
/bin/bash: set-title: command not found
```

It is obvious that the bash interpreter does not find the function set-title, but I do not know how to force the loading of the *.bashrc* file when the gnome-terminal is opened.

Comment: I hadvebeen down the rabbit hole. I ended up using `xfce4-terminal`. With just, for example: `xfce4-terminal --title foo` you're good to go.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` usually starts with a line which skips the rest of the file if the shell is not interactive (as with `bash -c '...'`).

Comment: With that being said, you don't need any (broken, as in the answer you point to) function in your `~/.bashrc`, you can just `printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'Terminal 1'` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question but before explaining the two solutions I have found, I will explain why what I was trying to do did not worked.

## Why my initial approach was wrong

If you have custom functions in your *~/.bashrc* file, like in my case the one for [setting the title of the terminal window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal/186167#186167), those functions will not be available in a terminal window that is opened from a bash script that executes commands in an automated way (as in the example of my question).

Thanks [user414777](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414777/user414777) for the hint. You were absolute right. My ~/.bashrc file contains the following code at the beginning:

```bsh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

By printing the option flags `$-` the result is *hB* (as expected is not an interactive shell), so obviously the `set-title` function that I have at the end of the *~/.bashrc*, will never be added to the shell.

## Solution 1 (Recommended): Using xfce4-terminal

As [schrodigerscatcuriosity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/338177/schrodigerscatcuriosity) suggested, this is the easiest solution for the problem. You might not like to install another terminal tool; if (like in my case) you are using Gnome and you use by default gnome-terminal, but the good side is that you can use the `xfce4-terminal` for the bash scripts and the `gnome-terminal` for your "human" interaction, so besides the titles you also have an extra level of categorization (in case you have many terminal windows opened).

The `xfce4-terminal` works a bit different than the `gnome-terminal` from within a bash script, but nothing you can not really figure out. In any case you can find below the solution with `xfce4-terminal`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

xfce4-terminal --title "Terminal 1" -e "bash -c 'echo Hello from terminal 1; exec /bin/bash'" &

xfce4-terminal --title "Terminal 2" -e "bash -c 'echo Hello from terminal 2; exec /bin/bash'" &
```

## Solution 2: Using xdotool

Another solution that I found to the problem is using `xdotool`. `xdotool` is a command line tool that can simulate/automate human interaction in the X11 window system.

This solution is overengineering the initial problem since it creates other issues such as the synchronization between the bash script and the X windows system, therefore it is necessary to introduce `sleep` commands in the bash script to give time to the X window manager to process the events. This synchronization issues make this solution not reliable since it does not works in 100% of the cases and the sleeping times need to be adapted to the speed of the window system.

Despite I do not recommend to go for this solution for the exposed problem in the question, I decided to introduce the solution in the answer for the shake completeness. Someone else might find it useful to apply this approach for some other purpose:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function set-title(){
    sleep 0.2
    
    # local WINDOW_ID=`xdotool getactivewindow`
    # local P_ID=`xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid`
    # echo "the window id is: $WINDOW_ID with PID: $P_ID"

    xdotool type "set-title $@"
    xdotool key KP_Enter
    sleep 0.2
}


gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "echo Hello from terminal 1;echo $-; exec /bin/bash";
# xdotool search --onlyvisible --class 'gnome-terminal'
set-title "Terminal 1"


gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "echo Hello from terminal 2; exec /bin/bash";
# xdotool search --onlyvisible --class 'gnome-terminal'
set-title "Terminal 2"
```

In this case, the function `set-title` included in the *~/.bashrc* file will work because after the commands have been executed in the `gnome-terminal`, the last instruction is `/bin/bash`. It loads the shell again and the next commands are forwarded to the terminal using `xdotool`, which creates the same events that a human would generate with the input devices (mouse, keyboard, etc ...).