# Create a Gnome multi-tab terminal pointing to various directories with custom titles

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I am having an issue with the tabs retaining their custom titles.

Here is my script:

```bsh
gnome-terminal \
  --tab --working-directory="${HOME}/git/project-1" -t "Project #1" \
  --tab --working-directory="${HOME}/git/project-2" -t "Project #2" \
  --tab --working-directory="${HOME}/git/project-3" -t "Project #3"
```

When the terminal first opens, I see all the tabs with their custom titles then they switch to their fully-qualified paths after their working directory is set.

- `user@~/git/project-1` instead of `Project #1`
- `user@~/git/project-2` instead of `Project #2`
- `user@~/git/project-3` instead of `Project #3`

---

### Edit

I even tried this, but it didn't work either. At the very least it opened the first tab, but still changed the title of the tab.

```bsh
gnome-terminal \
  --tab -t "Project #1" -- bash -c "cd ~/git/project-1; bash" \
  --tab -t "Project #2" -- bash -c "cd ~/git/project-2; bash" \
  --tab -t "Project #3" -- bash -c "cd ~/git/project-3; bash"
```

#### References

- [*Opening multiple tabs with gnome-terminal*](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154857/135944)
- [*How can I launch gnome-terminal with unique titles for multiple tabs?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248158/64783)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution (but I can't remember where). Maybe this is what you need.

Comment in you `.bashrc` this lines:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
: '
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
'
```